# R Find best set of all possible combinations that includes all values

Tags: r, select, optimization, combinations, nonlinear-optimization

After quite some google effort I hope somebody can help me with the problem, that appears quite simple to me, but is maybe more complicated than I thought:

I have a data.frame with three columns. The first two reflecting all possible combinations of five variables (1-5), the last the "strength" of the combination. I look for the five rows, which include all values of Var1 and Var2 (so values 1-5) and have the highest sum in the strength column. In the example beneath, it is the five rows with a strength of 1000, as they have the highest sum and all five values (1-5) are given in the first two columns.

How do I best approach that problem? Is there a package that has implemented that task? I found now the constrOptim() function, can I do it with that?

Code to create an example dataframe:

```
a <-cbind(expand.grid(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1)),
          strength = c(-11, 61, 230, 118, 156, 98, 169, 306, 6, -54,   
                        207, -32, 27, 128, 101, 19, -18, 32, 153, 14, 
                        63, 136, 165, 73, 35))
a <- a[order(a$strength, decreasing=T),]
```

Starting dataset:

```
 Var1 Var2 strength
 3    2      306
 3    1      230
 1    3      207
 2    2      169
 3    5      165
 5    1      156
 4    4      153
 2    5      136
 4    3      128
 4    1      118
 5    3      101
 1    2       98
 4    5       73
 1    5       63
 2    1       61
 5    5       35
 3    4       32
 3    3       27
 1    4       19
 5    4       14
 4    2        6
 1    1      -11
 2    4      -18
 2    3      -32
 5    2      -54
```

Not desired outcome:

```
 Var1 Var2 strength
 3    2      306
 3    1      230
 1    3      207
 2    2      169
 3    5      165
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
 Var1 Var2 strength
 3    2      306
 1    3      207
 5    1      156
 4    4      153
 2    5      136
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: The problem is in "where all variables are used in column one and two..". What does this mean?

Comment: The end solution should have five rows. And the first two columns (v1,v2) should both have all values, from one to five. Does this make it clear? I can post an example where I know the solution later. This example is random, hence I don't know the solution. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't know what the answer should look like how would you know if it was correct?

Comment: It appears that the question is how to sort and take the top 5 results:                           set.seed(4444)
a <- cbind(expand.grid(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1)),round(rnorm(n=25,mean=100,sd=100)))
a <- setNames(a,c("v1","v2","strengh"))

best <- a[order(-a$strengh),][1:5,]
rownames(best) <- NULL

best

Comment: Hi, it is not only sorting, but also making sure that the values 1-5 are available in the first two columns (Var1 and Var2). I made a new example, including desired outcome, that should make that clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a series of [aggregation](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/aggregate) and [merges](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/merge) between `Var1` and `Var2` columns:

```
# MERGE MAX AGGREGATES WHERE Var COL ARE EQUAL AND NOT EQUAL
mergedf1 <- merge(aggregate(strength ~ Var1, data=a[a$Var1==a$Var2,], FUN=max), 
                  a, by=c("Var1", "strength"))
mergedf2 <- merge(aggregate(strength ~ Var1, data=a[a$Var1!=a$Var2,], FUN=max), 
                  a, by=c("Var1", "strength"))

# STACK RESULTS 
mergedf <- rbind(mergedf1, mergedf2)

# FINAL MAX AGGREGATION AND MERGE
final <- merge(aggregate(strength ~ Var2, data=mergedf, FUN=max), 
               mergedf, by=c("Var2", "strength"))
final <- final[,c("Var1", "Var2", "strength")]                    # SORT COLUMNS
final <- final[with(final, order(-strength)),]                    # SORT ROWS

# REMOVE TEMP OBJECTS
rm(mergedf1, mergedf2, mergedf)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I had to reformulate the question so that it reflects my problem. See new desired output above.

Comment: What changed? I just used your data frame example and ran above code. End result matches your desired results. Just remove the `row.names()` line.

Comment: Hi, sorry, my example wasn't good. I made a new one. The issue is that each value (1-5) should be available in the columns Var1 and Var2. If I simply sort it by strength, this is not necessarily given. Although it is  possible in specific cases.

Comment: See update using a combination of `aggregate()` and `merge()`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the presented solution is the most effective one, but somehow I feel that we must go over the entire dataset to find the unique pairs (for example change the value of `(Var1 = 2, Var2 = 5, strength = 136)` to `(Var1 = 2, Var2 = 5, strength = 1)`. In order to find the unique pairs I use the apply function. First lets recreate the input:

```
a <-cbind(expand.grid(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1)),
          strength = c(-11, 61, 230, 118, 156, 98, 169, 306, 6, -54,   
                        207, -32, 27, 128, 101, 19, -18, 32, 153, 14, 
                        63, 136, 165, 73, 35))
a <- a[order(a$strength, decreasing=T),]
```

Now I prepare an empty matrix in which I will keep `Var1` in the first column, `Var2` in the second and `strength` in the third column.

```
V <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 3)
```

Next I write a function that will get one row from the ordered dataset `a`, will check if `Var1` and `Var2` are unique and if so, will store strength.

```
mf <- function(x){
    if( !(x[1] %in% V[,1]) & !(x[2] %in% V[,2])) {
        i <- x[1]
        V[i,1] <<- x[1]
        V[i,2] <<- x[2]
        V[i,3] <<- x[3]
    }
}
```

Now I apply the function on each row of `a`:

```
apply(a, 1, mf)
```

The needed values are stored in the matrix `V`:

```
V
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3  207
[2,]    2    5  136
[3,]    3    2  306
[4,]    4    4  153
[5,]    5    1  156
```

Sometimes, though going over the full dataset is not necessary (like in the example given), then we would like to be able to break the loop once the unique pairs were found. For that we can use a `for` loop. Here is the code:

```
a <-cbind(expand.grid(seq(1,5,1),seq(1,5,1)),
          strength = c(-11, 61, 230, 118, 156, 98, 169, 306, 6, -54,   
                       207, -32, 27, 128, 101, 19, -18, 32, 153, 14, 
                       63, 136, 165, 73, 35))
a <- a[order(a$strength, decreasing=T),]

V <- matrix(nrow=5,ncol=3)
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
    if( sum(is.na(V[,1])) == 0)
        break
    if( !(a[i,1] %in% V[,1]) & !(a[i,2] %in% V[,2])) {
        j <- a[i,1]
        V[j,1] <- a[i,1]
        V[j,2] <- a[i,2]
        V[j,3] <- a[i,3]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps, or at least will lead to improvements.